# Share or Push all images or services specified in docker compose.yml included mongoDB data

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have following compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
       easy-notes-app:
           container_name: nodejs-elliot
           image: elliotching/elliot-nodejs
           restart: always
           build: .
           ports:
             - "3003:3000"
           links:
             - mongo
       mongo:
             container_name: mongo
             image: mongo
             
             ports:
               - '27017:27017'
```

I want to

**Share everything specified in this yml included mongoDB and its data**

I've learned that without specifying `volumes`, data is kind of within container itself and is host independence. How can I do to push everything so that the person who pull the container already received the data together?

I tried `docker-compose push` but on another pc it does not pull mongo, and it seems like mongo is still need to manually install and is does not comes with mongo data.

Comment: Docker's main purpose is to isolate (~ containerize) environments. All you need to hit is `docker-compose up` and it will setup your two containers. Regarding data migrations, there is a lot of information on [Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo). This is super simple compared to setting up everything manually.

Comment: Sorry my bad, minimum requirement is `docker-compose.yml` must be copied to another PC, and `docker-compose up`. I was trying `docker run elliotching/elliot-nodejs`

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you want to send docker images and its containers data to another system completely so correct me if i am wrong.

1. first you have to use volumes to make sure of data persistence in your container even after restarting your host. copy the volume on the host for transfer or use scp to copy from container to host.
2. to save an image as a tar file

```
docker save -o <path for generated tar file> <image name>
```

3. in another system use this code to load images

```
docker load -i <path to image tar file>
```

4. make sure image names are tagged as your local repository not docker hub or another repository.
5. then

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: it will be much appreciate if u can share more details about your answer, such as how to create volume? do I need to specify in yml or run a cli commands?

Comment: to create volume docker volume create --name <name>  then to connect to volume docker run -d -p 8080:8083 --name <name> -v <host path>:/<container path>  <imageName> this is the example with docker run

Comment: in your docker-compose use it like this -- volumes:
      - data:/usr/share/yourapp/data